# Códigos no debug console têm algum significado?

Tags: flutter, dart

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma documentação que explica mais detalhado o que significa esse `I/flutter`,etc, e o código entre parênteses. As vezes passa desapercebido no debug nos atentamos nas `exception` e na linha onde ocorreu. 

Tenho essa curiosidade e não encontrei nada específico.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa informações são do LogCat.

Se você abrir seu projeto no Android Studio e abrir a aba LogCat, verá que a cada segundo serão geradas milhares de mensagens, que são relacionadas a tudo que está ocorrendo em seu celular.

> Imagem ilustrativa

[image: Imagem ilustrativa]
Como pode ser visto na imagem acima, ao debugar meu projeto o AS filtra apenas as mensagens do meu projeto *com.example.sales_catalog*.
É assim também, que o Flutter identifica os Exceptions e mensagem relacionadas a ele.

Em relação ao código *I/Flutter (22742)*, esse código entre parenteses é meio que o código relacionado aquele processo que o Flutter está escutando, no caso teu projeto que está debugando

Answer (score 0):

No exemplo acima, `"I/D"` são os níveis de log.
Podendo ser:

- V: Verbose (menor prioridade)
- D: Debug
- I: Info
- W: Warning
- E: Error
- F: Fatal
- S: Silent (alta prioridade, não imprime nada)

`Flutter` : Tag(titulo)

`(22742)` : Número do processo

Após os `:`  é o texto que detalha o log.

Fontes:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865538/understanding-logcat-output-when-written-to-file
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat